# CouchDB app Toast won't load attachments

Tags: couchdb, toast

I'm learning CouchDB. I'm trying to load the example app Toast onto a local database and then take it apart to see how it works. The problem is that it isn't working, and I feel like the error is obvious but I just don't quite see it.

I've downloaded the development code from Github as a zip, extracted it into `CouchDB/bin/toast`, then used erica to push Toast onto my CouchDB. Here is my local Toast in Futon:

http://puu.sh/5hc2V.png

It appears to have been pushed correctly. However, when I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:5984/toast/_design/toast/index.html` as erica instructs, I get this (with Chrome console):

http://puu.sh/5hc8X.png

I assumed the resources might be missing, but I checked, they are there both in the attachments for `/vendor/` on CouchDB and in my file system from where erica pushed the application. Nonetheless, they do not appear to load.

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These resources should under _attachments, otherwise you'll get HTTP Error 404 Not found.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! They are under _attachments, in the "vendor" section: http://puu.sh/5j5g8.png

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, it explains a lot. The dependencies are located in `vendor/couchapp/_attachments`. Should be in `_attachments/vendor/...`

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, thank you. I used erica to deploy the chat program, and it deployed those files into the vendor directory. Is there any way I can tell erica to put them in the right place? Also, is there any sort of guide you know of about Erica? its documentation is rather sparse right now...

Comment: the only kind of documentation is to launch erica with --help parameter :)

Comment: Whenever I launch erica with the --help parameter, it just gives me usage options :( It seems --help or -h aren't implemented.  http://puu.sh/5mc31.png